# Remove all Key Shortcuts from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to remove all Key-Shortcuts from Visual Studio, so I can assign them from scratch? I don't mean to reset them to their default value, but to nothing.

Comment: FYI this tool illustrates the extent of the problem: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ce3b73c-2284-4b95-b61d-6de74aa8dfe6  - if you export all predefined shortcuts & sort by keyboard combination, you see that for example, there are 6 pre-assigned meanings to "Alt+1".  Being able to wipe out all that stuff so that new assignments don't have such a high percentage chance of colliding with existing ones would be useful.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043624/programmatically-reset-visualstudio-shortcuts

Comment: How come Visual Studio is so outdated? I'm in shock to have to struggle for such features. Do they even take a look at modern IDEs?

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to do the same with my installation of Visual Studio - to remove all shortcuts and assign my own, from scratch. I managed to achieve this with a hacky [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) script.

If you select a command that is bound to a shortcut, within the 'Keyboard' section of the Visual Studio Options dialog, the 'Remove' button should activate. Notice that the 'R' is underlined (which, if isn't, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down).

[image: VS Keyboard Options]

On Windows, this generally means that the button can be activated by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and the underlined character.

Removing all shortcuts is then a matter of repeatedly un-binding the selected command with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and selecting the next command (<kbd>↓</kbd>), which I automated using the following script:

```
#z::              ; Binds to Win + Z.
Loop, 3500        ; Loops 3500 times.
{
    Send, {Down}  ; Sends the down keystroke.
    Send, !r      ; Sends the Alt + R keystroke.
    Sleep, 30     ; Delays for 30ms.
}
Return
```

Adjust the number of repetitions (`3500`), and the [hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) to invoke the script (`#z` which means <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>) as necessary. Run the script, select the first command in the list, press (in this case) <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, and wait for it to complete.

Note that commands don't always have a single key-binding, and therefore you might have to run the script a couple of times, or better yet, send the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keystroke multiple times a single repetition.

The script will attempt to remove un-assigned shortcuts too, upon which Windows will play a 'beeping' sound and therefore make sure to mute Windows before running the script.

Comment: This is very much a hack-ish solution, but running it multiple times seems to remove all shortcuts. Thanks! (isn't there some kind of configuration file where one can go and just remove all shortcuts?) -- Edit: On the German language version of Visual Studio, the hotkey is "E" (as in "Entfernen"), so "!r" has to be replaced with "!e".